# SignTool not picking up the certificate

Tags: windows, security, certificate, code-signing, signtool

I have self signed a certificate and installed it in the pc.

However, it is not currently picked up by the SignTool.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea why? Any input on this is highly appreciated.

The pc is running on Windows 8.1 Pro.

**Update**

Following suggestion of @Robert, I have installed it to personal section. But still I am not able to sign the exe file.

[image]

Command:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit\signtool.exe"  sign /n "MyCert" /fd SHA256 setup.exe

Comment: The screen shot shows the trusted rot certificates section. Windows would never use a certificate from this section for signing. Root CAs are only for verifying. If you have a certificate + key install it into the section "Personal". Note  that for code signing the certificate need to include special [extended] key usage options. And please don't post terminal output as screenshot, simply copy the content and copy and paste it into your post.

Comment: By [extended] key usage options, do you mean intended purpose of the certificate. If it is, my certificate has "Code Signing" listed as the purpose.

Comment: Then most likely your certificate is missing an extended key usage flag or an extension like ` 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3` which is AFAIK required for Authenticode code signing. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/505384e4-b314-432c-9132-fc6cf9f71b44/can-a-site-certificate-be-used-to-sign-a-software?forum=windowssecurity

Comment: Do you know how to verify it?

Comment: It works if I use the /f switch and specify the pfx file though. But I have to get the certificate from the store for configuring the build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `signtool.exe` looks for certificates in the user store (`certmgr.msc`) not the machine store (`certlm.msc`).

Try to move the certificate to your user store.

Comment: The two certificate stores you mention look almost identical. To know which is which, look at the title bar. If it says "Certificates - Current User", it's the user store. If it says "Certificates - Local Computer", it's the machine store. BOTH windows have a "Personal->Certificates" folder, which makes it even more confusing. But it HAS to say "Current User" at the TOP to be the correct, User Store AND Personal certificate location.